# Symfony - How to get the main route of the controller?

Tags: symfony, path, routes, controller

How do I get just the route of the Controller class? like in this case is `/book`

Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;


/**
 * @Route("/book")
 */
class BookController extends AbstractController
{

    /**
     * @Route("/")
     */
    public function index() : Response
    {
        return $this->render('book.html.twig');
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/something")
     */
    public function doSomething(){
        // do stuff

        // get the main path/route of this controller; that is '/book', and not '/book/something'

        // do stuff
    }
}
```

I found this:  `$path = $this->getParameter('kernel.project_dir')`. It doesn't really matter with this, but I hope there is something similar.

Comment: That kind of stuff is all compiled and cached so I don't think /book by itself is stored somewhere.  Perhaps you could explain why you need it and an alternative approach could be suggested.  Otherwise, just store it as a class constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what exactly you want and how flexible you want it to be, named routes might help:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;


/**
 * @Route("/book", name="book")
 */
class BookController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("", name="_index")
     */
    public function index() : Response
    {
        return $this->render('book.html.twig');
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/something", name="_something")
     */
    public function doSomething(){
        // do stuff

        $baseRoute = $this->generateUrl('book_index'); // returns /book

        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a working solution.

1. get the actual route
2. transform it into an array thanks to the '/' separetor
3. take only the second item of the array (the first one is always empty because the first character of the path is '/')

[image]